# How to know how a loop has ended

Tags: java, for-loop, break

While writing a program, I have gotten into a strange situation. I need to know whether a `for loop` has ended normally, or due to `break`. Is there any way to know this?

Comment: 1. debug. 2. System,out.print()

Comment: use a boolean flag and set it to true right before breaking.

Comment: Set a boolean, define an index outside of the loop and check it against the length/upper-bound, etc.

Comment: Best thing would be to pickup a programming tutorial for beginners. Not trying to be a jerk, but this question is a bit too rudimentary for the SO audience.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use break, but an additional condition:

```
boolean stop = false;
for (int i = 0; i < N && !stop; i++) {
    ...
    stop = true;   // instead of break
}

if (stop) {
    // whatever you want to do on break
}
```

This is at least the way I learned it, because it allows you to reason about your program. After the loop, we know that

```
!(i < N && !stop)
```

which is equivalent to

```
i >= N || stop
```

Does that matter? Maybe not in real-life, but in academia people love to prove properties of their code :-)

Comment: That only works if there are no other statements after `stop = true;`

Comment: @assylias absolutely, that's why there are `...` before that line but not after ;-)

Comment: what I was trying to say is that this approach is not strictly equivalent to break and will need an extra if/else if break was not the last statement. In which case BryPie's approach could be more appropriate.

Comment: So instead, set your `stop` (which you might want to spell differently for the specific condition: `brokenDueToOPsCondition`), and then break.

Answer (score 2):

You could set a boolean variable (BreakExecuted or something) equal to false before your for loop, then set it to true before each break.

Answer (score 0):

The only language that provides syntax for this is python, and even there it is not very popular.

This problem is common in search loops, where the usual solution is to maintain an extra flag, such as `has_found`, which is initialized as false, and set to true just before the break is issued. Outside of the for loop you'll just check the `has_found` flag.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
boolean normalFinish = false;
for (int i = 0; i < N && !stop; i++) {

    //first statement of loop
    normalFinish = false;

    ...

    // last statement of loop
    normalFinish  = true;   
}

if(normalFinish) {
   System.out.println("Finished normally");
}
```

The idea is, if the loop finishes normally normalFinish wil be true otherwise it will be false.